# MongoDB - Is there a way to join two collections and filter by values into array field?

Tags: mongodb, aggregate-functions

I'm working on a web app project which requires me to query a MongoDB to retrieve some data. I'm really a beginner in non-relational DB.
Basically I have these 2 collections with the following schemas:

Actors
name: string | gender: string ecc...

Movies
_id | year: number | title: string | actors : Array

In particular, that array is structured like this:
[0:{0:'name', 1: 'surname'}, 1: {...} ecc..]

What i need is a query that returns the name, the gender and the list of movies of a given actor name, so i tried the $lookup function but the problem is that I don't know how to access that to match the name.

```
db.actors.aggregate([
{
  $lookup:
   {
    from: "movies",
    let: { name: "$_id"},
    pipeline: [
     {
       $match:
        {
          $expr: 
             {
                { $eq: [ "$actors",  "$$name" ] },
             }
        }
     }
    ],

    as: "movies"
}
}
])
```

Of course, it doesn't work because actors is a nested array. Any solutions?

Comment: Try { $unwind:$actors } before $match